# React Native: Alert message doesn't work when called frequently

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a react native app. In the app I am using an event listener to listen for some actions from native modules, which works fine.

When the event listener captures the event, `console.log` outputs, then it calls another function which outputs `console.log` again, which all works.

But when the function also displays an Alert it displays the first time but is may not if displaying the Alert is called multiple times.

What could be the issue? Can I display an Alert frequently?

Here is the source code :

```
class Details extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('tagDetected', (data)=>{
      console.log(data.serial)
      this.attendBySerial(data.serial)
    });
  }
  attendBySerial(i){
    console.log('Attending', i)
    Alert.alert(
      'NFC Tag Detected',
      JSON.stringify(i)
    );
  }

  render(){

    return(
      ///.......
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling an alert over and over again may have unintended consequences such as this technically. However I think you may face bigger problems down the road with user experience. I think it's likely getting hit with multiple alerts will leave the user annoyed.

Regardless I think you should probably set up a queue to manage your alerts as they are captured and should display them one at a time. You can manage when they are displayed by displaying the next alert when the last closes if an alert exists in the queue.